# To find maximum numbers of 1 in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Below is my code to find the index of a row that has maximum numbers of `1` in a sorted 2D matrix.

```
public class RowWithMax1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[][]={{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,1,1}};
    int rows=0;
    int rowe=a.length-1;
    int cole=a.length;
    int cols=0;
    //System.out.println("len="+a.length);
    int index=0;
    int count[]=new int[a[0].length];
     int k=0;
     int max=0;
    while(rows<=rowe)
    {
        count[k]=0;
        while(a[rows][cole]==1 && cole!=cols)
        {

            count[k]++;
            cole--;
            //System.out.println("cole="+cole);

        }
        System.out.println(k+" "+count[k]);
        if(count[k]>max)
        {
            max=count[k];
            index=k;
        }
        rows++;
        k++;
        cole=a.length;
    }
System.out.println("index"+index);
}

}
```

The code works fine for the first and the last row but, for the second row it gives count less than `1`. For example, in the second row number of `1` is `4`, but the code returns `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you skip the first element as you traverse backwards in the row. The while breaks as soon as `cole == cols`. You better use a for loop for traversal then break out from it when the first condition becomes true, or just change the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I did some refactoring and it works:

```
public class RowWithMax1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[][]={{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,1,1}};
    int rowsLength=a.length;
    System.out.println("rowsLength " + rowsLength);
    int biggestIndex=0;
    int count[]=new int[a[0].length];
    int maxCount=0;

    for(int currentRow=0; currentRow < rowsLength; currentRow++)
    {

        int colsLength=a[currentRow].length;
        System.out.println("Row " + currentRow + " colsLength " + colsLength);
        count[currentRow]=0;

        for(int currentCol=0; currentCol < colsLength; currentCol++)
        {
            if ( a[currentRow][currentCol] == 1)
                count[currentRow]++;

        }
        System.out.println("Row " + currentRow+" has "+count[currentRow] + " x 1");

        if(count[currentRow]>maxCount)
        {
            maxCount=count[currentRow];
            biggestIndex=currentRow;
        }           
    }

    System.out.println("Biggest index "+biggestIndex);
}

}
```

Comment: OK, and now you can make your inner while loop a simple for loop as well.